# How can I Port Forward to an istio VirtualService?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have setup VirtualService and ServiceEntry for a few services outside my kubernetes cluster.
My apps can access them without any issue.
I was wondering if it would be somehow possible to perform a port-forward to these services via `kubectl`, similar to how you would port-forward into a pod or a service.

This works:
`kubectl port-forward service/my-service 8080:80`

This Doesn't:
`kubectl port-forward vs/my-virtual-service 6379:6379`

I get:

> error: no kind "VirtualService" is registered for version
> "networking.istio.io/v1beta1" in scheme
> "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/scheme/register.go:72"

Comment: Port forwarding can be done to istio-ingressgateway service but not to virtual service.  More details of service and virtual service of istio are in their official documentation https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/

Comment: You should add this as answer, instead of a comment.

Comment: this was really a good comment, but not an answer

Answer (score 1):

Port forwarding can be done to istio-ingressgateway service but not to virtual service. More details of service and virtual service of istio are in their [official documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/)

One more option is to change istio-ingressgateway service to NodePort

```
kubectl edit svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system
```